# Run c++ function from python

Tags: python, c++, ueye

I am trying to access GPIO of my IDS camera via python using pyueye. The original function is defined as: `INT is_IO(HIDS hCam, UINT nCommand, void* pParam, UINT cbSizeOfParam)`. This is an example of usage:

```
Example 2

INT nRet = IS_SUCCESS;

 

IO_GPIO_CONFIGURATION gpioConfiguration;

 

// Set configuration of GPIO1 (OUTPUT LOW)

gpioConfiguration.u32Gpio = IO_GPIO_1;

gpioConfiguration.u32Configuration = IS_GPIO_OUTPUT;

gpioConfiguration.u32State = 0;

 

nRet = is_IO(hCam, IS_IO_CMD_GPIOS_SET_CONFIGURATION, (void*)&gpioConfiguration,

            sizeof(gpioConfiguration));
```

I'm trying to do it in python as follows:

```
from pyueye import ueye
from ctypes import pointer
gpioConfiguration = ueye.IO_GPIO_CONFIGURATION 
gpioConfiguration.u32Gpio = ueye.IO_GPIO_1
gpioConfiguration.u32Configuration = ueye.IS_GPIO_OUTPUT
gpioConfiguration.u32State = 1

pt = pointer(gpioConfiguration)
stat = ueye.is_IO(hCam, ueye.IS_IO_CMD_GPIOS_SET_CONFIGURATION,byref(gpioConfiguration),ueye.sizeof(gpioConfiguration))
```

But I get the error: TypeError: *type* must have storage info.
Any ideas on what I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is actually being thrown by your call to `ctypes.pointer` rather than `pyueye`.  Specifically, `gpioConfiguration` is a `_ctypes.PyCStructType` rather than an *instance*.  (This is what was meant by 'must have storage', i.e. you actually have to store something looking like that struct before you can get a pointer to it.  This is likely a bit odd coming from c++, but ctypes thinks of structs as being like Classes you have to instantise. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html?highlight=pointer#structures-and-unions).

So if you really needed a pointer you would have to do:

```py
myConfig = gpioConfiguration()
pt = pointer(myConfig)
# you probably want to set properties on the *instance*:
myConfig.u32Gpio = ueue.IO_GPIO_1
myConfig.u32State = 1
# and then use this instance later when passing `byref`
```

If you just need to pass these params by reference, see the section on [byref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html?highlight=pointer#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference) (though this too needs an instance).

I don't have a camera to test with sadly (they look very good fun), so this is far as I can go.  But hopefully you can get the semantics of `ueye` behaving for you.

Incidentally, you don't need semicolons in python (unlike in JS you *really* don't and nobody thinks you should put them in)

Comment: Thank you, the error is gone now. Sadly the output is not being set but that's another problem I guess. Of course I know that there are no semicolons in Python, just an copy paste error :D

Comment: @helpneeded does the latest edit help?

Comment: sadly not, I had to leave the byref() out... but using pointer and byref is unneccessary or?

Comment: byref() and pointer() are mutually exclusive, yes.  byref() is just cheaper than making a pointer and then passing the pointer, if you don't need to reuse the pointer anywhere.  Regardless of which way you do it, you are setting the properties *on the instance* aren't you?  They won't carry over if you set them on the class and then instantise (test it).

Comment: Yes I tested it, sorry for not being clear about that! It did not help but there might also be some other function I need to run beforehand just not sure about that yet...

Comment: ah, that's a pity.  Good luck!